# Displaying text above and below the image

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a page where i am displaying an image and trying to put some text just above and below the image.

This is how i am trying to do it.

```
    <div data-role="page"  >
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>First image</h1>

                </div><!--header ends-->
                <div data-role="content" >
                    <center>
                                <h3> image name </h3>
                    <img src="Firstimage.png" alt=""  style="height:100%; width:auto;" />
                                <h3> autor name </h3>           
</center>   

                </div>
                <div data-role="footer"   >

                </div> <!--footer ends here -->
            </div>
```

The space between image name and image is too big and page is scrolling. also same with author name also..

I went to get the image name and author name just above and below the image respectively.

How can i do that?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Use a reset class for h1,h2,h3,....
Here in this case use,

```
h3 {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
```

And **center** tag is obsolute, try to avoid it and use CSS class instead.

Answer (score 0):

`<h3>` has its own padding(or margin). so just use `<div>` with some styling instead.